# Retrieve user login information using Fb

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm doing a Facebook login feature, but I can not currently retrieve the user's avatar because it's in a multi-layer array. Below is my code

```
function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
    'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
});
```

And this is the array of Facebook returns

```
{  
  "id":"486438998406684",
  "name":"Đức Duy",
  "picture":{  
    "data":{  
      "is_silhouette":false,
      "url":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/18157499_427629980954253_1656751371029691275_n.jpg?oh=d22f044a4974ca685029b20b12cea799&oe=5A247DD0"
    }
  }
}
```

Currently I only get the name and ID, I do not know how to get the url url. Someone know how to get help me.
Thank you everyone for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Use `response.picture.data.url` to get the image location